# WPF console application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I wrote a window application in WPF in C # but now comes the need to run it only in console mode. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and have already changed in the Project -> Output type -> tab to the "Console application". There is of course a console, but also an empty program window (empty form). My first problem is how to solve it, and the second is how to return a specific result from this console (in the sense of some kind, eg 0,1,2). The point is that this application (this .exe file) will be used in another program.

Comment: Look in your `Main` method and remove the forms code.

Comment: And I think the "result" you're looking for is the "exit code".

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to retrofit an application to do 2 things, why don't you just put the relevant code in a class library (we call it a business layer), then you can reference it from any projects

I.e You can make a console app reference it, or your WPF app. You can call it from a web service, or you can even call it from existing apps just by including the referencing in the project.